# Overlaying the Action Bar not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-styles

I was following [official developer's guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html) to overlay actionbar.

my `style.xml` is as following:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTheme</item>

</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

My midSdkVersion is 14 and expected output is similar to that on official guide:[image].

instead, in my case the output is: [image]

(I have set background color to activity...but it isn't overlaying action bar.)

Please help me if anything I'm doing is wrong.

## EDIT:

I wanted similar action bar like this in airnb and many other apps. Can anyone give me complete answer for this?

[image]

Comment: Please check your manifest file. You might using wrong theme instead of CustomActionBarTheme.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer can you write a complete answer  with code? I'll appreciate it. thanks.

Comment: you are setting the actionbar to be overlayed, but you did not set the background of the actionbar to be transparent. try adding `<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>` with `@drawable/actionbar_background` is a semi transparent png image

Comment: @Krupal can you please update your question with code of your manifest file So that i can come to know the thing for which i am asking about...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I see some misunderstandings in your code:

1. `windowActionBarOverlay` should be specified on your theme not on your `ActionBar`'s style.
2. No reason to use a `Holo` with a support theme. This just breaks your supportability.

Try this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!--For compatibility-->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<color name="transparent_black">#80000000</color>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent_black</item>
    <!--For compatibility-->
    <item name="background">@color/transparent_black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I am not agree with your first point. because it is clearly mention that theme should be declared style and you can use it like below: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme

Comment: I have used your solution and it is working fine. But title from `ActionBar` is gone. Can you help with that?

Comment: this is just perfect!

Comment: add padding to the layout             android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: The 'For compatibility' part did the trick, even when running on a device with API version 23.. the default full screen activity generated by android studio didn't add that!

Answer (score 4):

i think you miss this point of [developer guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html)

**Enable Overlay Mode**

**For Android 3.0 and higher only**

style.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**For Android 2.1 and higher**

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Specify Layout Top-margin**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

and I have two example links Please have a Look on them for more clarification.

[Android Tutorial: Overlay with User Instructions](http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/android-tutorial-overlay-with-user-instructions/)

[Pushing the ActionBar to the Next Level](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/)

Comment: Perfect, if anyone is using Sliding Tabs and wants to show and hide the ActionBar on scroll, the key here is `android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>

<style name="OverlayActionBarTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Holo.ActionBar.Overlay</item>
</style>

<style
    name="Holo.ActionBar.Overlay"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#80000000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching for two hours I feel obliedged to add this answer here.

What did the trick for me was to add all 6 of the following lines to `styles.xml`:

```
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>

    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
```

As far as I understand all those lines do the same thing, but different API levels only listen for certain lines. I should mention that I use minimum API level 19.

Answer (score 0):

You just missed that you need to set up the overlaying in your application theme as said in the [documention](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html#EnableOverlay)

```
 <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
```

Please feed back if the problem isn't solve with that ;)

Answer (score -1):

I do completely custom views, so, the activity layout would fill all the screen and put custom LinearLayout at the top with all the buttons and icons inflated